# Zend_Log with mail

Tags: zend-framework

Has anyone succeed to send an mail(SMTP GOOGLE) with Zend_Log.I found this http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.writers.html
**Chapter 32.2.4. Writing to Email** but by default it's using mail(), but I want to use SMTP.So until now my code looks like this:

> ```
>   $mailconf = array('ssl'=>'ssl',
>             'auth' => 'login',
>                     'username' => 'mymail@gmail.com',
>                     'password' => 'mypass',
>                     'port'=>'465');
> ```

```
    $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $mailconf);                


    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setFrom('from.website@example.com')
         ->addTo('mysecondmail@site.com');

    $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Mail($mail);
    // On fixe le sujet du mail
    $writer->setSubjectPrependText('Important Log Events');

    // Only email warning level entries and higher.
    $writer->addFilter(Zend_Log::WARN);

    $loggerZendMail = new Zend_Log();
    $loggerZendMail->addWriter($writer);

    $loggerZendMail->log('unable to connect to database',Zend_Log::WARN);
```

I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Log_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail' in C:\wamp\www\zf_log\Zend\Log\Writer\Mail.php:256 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\zf_log\Zend\Log.php(84): Zend_Log_Writer_Mail->shutdown() #1 C:\wamp\www\zf_log\Zend\Controller\Action.php(512): Zend_Log->__destruct() #2 C:\wamp\www\zf_log\Zend\Controller\Action.php(512): IndexController->indexAction() #3 C:\wamp\www\zf_log\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(288): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction') #4 C:\wamp\www\zf_log\Zend\Controller\Front.php(945): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #5 C:\wamp\www\zf_log\index.php(30): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #6 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\zf_log\Zend\Log\Writer\Mail.php on line 256

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the transport for Zend_Mail to use

Example:

```
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check if SMTP is enabled on server.

Answer (score 0):

Use TLS instead of SSL also check if the port 587 works

so the below config should work

```
$mailconf = array('ssl'=>'tls', 'auth' => 'login', 'username' => 'mymail@gmail.com', 'password' => 'mypass', 'port'=>'587');
```